# Indexing pdf documents

Tags: pdf, solr, full-text-indexing, apache-tika, solr-cell

What the best way to index pdf documents? Should I index them by converting pdf documents to txt or there is a better way to index pdf files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about solr: see the [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler).